# Is there an alternative to --add-opens command line parameters for just ported applications to a newer Java?

Tags: java, java-11, java-17, java-module

Is there an alternative to --add-opens command line parameters for just ported applications to a newer Java?

To make our venerable monolithic application make to run on Java 11 and Java 17, I had to add several --add-opens. I would like to keep the application non-modular/monolithic for the time being.

To make it run I have to add a rather lengthy list of --add-opens to our already long list of VM parameters. Example:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.desktop/java.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.desktop/java.swing.table=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.desktop/java.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED
...
```

And the list goes on and on. It works, but it's unwieldy. We already have many command line parameters, VM and program arguments. I'm afraid we can hit CLI limits at some point somewhere. All those arguments also make it more fiddly to start the app from an IDE.

Is there an alternative?
I there something like module-info.java file to declare openings globally, for non-modular project? A file I can keep inside project, inside produced JAR?

Comment: There’s some confusion about the terms on your side. An application can be non-modular and/or monolithic without specifying these options. These `--add-opens` options are only necessary if you hack into the internals of the specified package using deep reflection. If you really need *all of them*, your application is not non-modular or monolithic but a horrible hack. And you can’t say you “ported applications to a newer Java” if you just run them on the newer Java but rely on internals which can change in every minor update.

Comment: It's a large system I'm currently working on as contractor, 99.99% is not my code. Its core dates back to 1995. Most add-opens are needed for introspection done by serialization frameworks. I had to fix several direct calls to internal JDK APIs, luckily there were only a few. There are several external libraries we have no source code for from internal teams no longer existing. Challenging job. I like it :)

Comment: Serialization frameworks might sound like legitimate use cases but still are fragile and creating version dependencies when they’re accessing internals of the core Java classes. It also begs the question why you are updating the Java version when keeping the application code and the frameworks (and all of their ticking time bombs) in the state of 1995 is considered fine. By the way, the first Java version was released in 1996 and had only eight packages. Adding an `--add-opens ` for all of them wouldn’t be too hard, but I doubt that code relying on the 1.0 internal form still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are producing an executable jar file, you could use the `Add-Opens` manifest attribute. When running the app using `java -jar <jar file>` that should avoid having to pass all the flags. See: https://openjdk.org/jeps/261#Packaging:-Modular-JAR-files

The `java` executable also supports expanding command line flags from a file using `@`:

```
java @options org.main.Main
```

The lines in the `options` file will be 'expanded' into the command line. So, you could put the needed options into a file that you add to the project, and then use it with `@`. I'm not sure if your IDE will support that though (though, arguably you could also check your IDE run configuration into the project).

In general though, you should try to reduce the reflective access to JDK internals, so that you don't need these flags in the first place. This will also give you better portability between JDK versions.

Comment: The argument file is the more versatile option to go. It works everywhere. Manifest doesn't work when running the app or tests from IDE (IntelliJ) - rendering it useless for us.

Comment: The downside of argument file is, if I understand well, it has to be outside the app JAR. So if you intend to distribute your app a one neat JAR, you have to include Manifest file. And with that you end up having to keep two separate add-open lists: argument file for running in IDE and Manifest file for production run of the JAR. Or wrap JAR and argument file into a ZIP and have installer. Huh, no ideal solutions in sight.

Comment: The link to the official documentation about Java Command-Line Argument Files can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#java-command-line-argument-files